# Polynomials of odd degree over $F_{p}$ have a root in $F_{p}$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I'm reading Broker's paper "**CONSTRUCTING SUPERSINGULAR ELLIPTIC CURVES**", which gives an algorithm of constructing supersingular elliptic curves over $F_{p}$ (where $p$ is a prime number).

> **Theorem 2.1.** [Deuring's lifting theorem] Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over a number field $L$ whose endomorphism ring is the maximal order $\mathcal{O}_K$ in an imaginary quadratic field $K$, and let $\mathfrak{p} \mid p$ be a prime of $L$ where $E$ has good reduction. Then $E$ mod $\mathfrak{p}$ is supersingular  if and only if $p$ does not split in $K$ using Deuring's lifting theorem.

"Let $E$ be an elliptic curve as in the Theorem 2.1, and $P_K$ be a Hilbert class polynomial (so its degree equals the class number $h_K$ of $K$). If we now take $K$ such that $p$ remains inert in $\mathcal{O}_K$, then the roots of $P_K \in \overline{F}_p[x]$ are $j$-invariants of supersingular curves. Since the $j$-invariant of a supersingular curve is contained in $F_{p^2}$, the polynomial $P_K$ splits over $F_{p^2}$."

I understand up to this part. In the next paragraph he says

"If we take $K$ so that the class number $h_k$ is odd, then $P_K \in F_{p}[x]$ has a root in $F_{p}$."

Why does odd degree imply $P_K$ has a root in $F_{p}$? I know that polynomial of odd degree over real numbers must have a real root, but I'm not sure if a similar statement holds for general field, or at least for $F_{p}$.

Comment: Please avoid such questions where you are referring to a lot of non-trivial theorems to finally ask a trivial question.

Comment: @reuns Well, I was just providing as much as details I can with some context. Unless I feel confident enough that this can be reduced to a simple question (if I knew that, probably I didn't ask the question in the first place), it's not clear that the result is from a simple fact or non-trivial theorems, especially when I'm reading a research paper where some trivial/non-trivial facts are missing. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P_K(x)=\prod_j f_j(x)^{e_j}\in \Bbb{F}_{p}[x]$$
Let $E$ be the splitting field. Because every finite extension of $\Bbb{F}_p$ is Galois we get that $$[E:\Bbb{F}_p]=lcm(f_1,\ldots,f_J)$$
Thus $E\subset \Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ tells us that $\deg(f_j)\le 2$.

That $\deg(P_K)$ is odd tells us that not all $\deg(f_j)$ is even, ie. some $\deg(f_i)=1$ and $P_K$ has a root.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't in general. Take for instance $$x^3 + x + 1 \pmod{5}.$$ The essential fact is that the polynomial splits over $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ (cf. reuns' answer).